# Error when running database seeder through Heroku

Tags: laravel, shell, heroku

I am unable to setup a packages folder structure with `db:seed` on Laravel framework.

I was able to deploy and migrate the regular Laravel project on heroku,
but I am having issue trying to use the class argument for the `artisan db:seed` command.

my folders structure:

```
root-dir/packages/clientname/projectname/app
root-dir/packages/clientname/projectname/config
root-dir/packages/clientname/projectname/database/seeders
root-dir/packages/clientname/projectname/resources
```

In composer I have autoload > psr-4 mapped to the packages seeders folder

```
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "ClientName\\ProjectName\\Database\\Seeders\\": "packages/clientname/projectname/database/seeders/"
        }
    },
```

running the following command

```
$ heroku run --app client-project php artisan db:seed --class=\\ClientName\\ProjectName\\Database\\Seeders\\DatabaseSeeder
```

returns an error

```
In Container.php line 811:
Target class [Database\Seeders\ClientNameProjectNameDatabaseSeedersDatabaseSeeder] does not exist.
```

Note the backslashes have been removed. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Seems like the class name is not getting passed properly from your command. There's probably some escaping going on with the heroku command. Try 4 backslashes.

Comment: Thanks, 4 blackslashes did solved the issue. Now I just have to figure out why the package tables and seeding are still not showing up in postgreSQL database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking out [the source for this command](https://github.com/heroku/cli/blob/master/packages/run/src/commands/run/index.ts), it appears there's a fair bit of escaping going on. I would suggest either double-escaping your backslashes like this:

```sh
heroku run --app client-project php artisan db:seed --class=\\\\ClientName\\\\ProjectName\\\\Database\\\\Seeders\\\\DatabaseSeeder
```

Or try some quoting around the command:

```sh
heroku run --app client-project 'php artisan db:seed --class=\\ClientName\\ProjectName\\Database\\Seeders\\DatabaseSeeder'
```